# Inserting tags by clicking on the objet

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a question about the coordinates of the model.

Would it be possible to register a problem with a tag in the model, defining the exact location by clicking on the model?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/savnJ.png)

PS.: on this example, only it is possible to use central coordinates of the object

Comment: To get the exact position of the mouse when clicking an object you need to raycast and retrieve the exact position where an object is hit. Curious on why you would want to do this. Wouldnt specifying the part of an object in the description of the issue be a lot more concise and clear ? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact x,y,z value, use this 'ALT-key pivot point' technique, to get the surface point of a model, instead of it's centroid:

https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/issues/2

**Second part:**

Once you have the x,y,z value, you can replace 'centroid' position calulation, in this post:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/placing-custom-markup-dbid

```
// get the center of the dbId (based on its fragIds bounding boxes)
const pos = this.viewer.worldToClient(this.getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(id).center());
```

Does that help?